# How to smooth transition between two parts of the object

Tags: modeling

How to smooth transition between two parts of the object?

[image]

[image]

No idea what to do to make it look smooth after subdiv

Comment: do you have a picture of the original object you want to copy? It would help to understand what is the shape at this exact area

Comment: Go to the sculpting window and use dynamic topology on a brush to smooth that crease. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a vertex inside your mesh. Use the modeling features to try to take away that inside vertex while retaining good topology.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would try using the 'Intersect' or 'Union' modes for the Boolean modifier. Add it to either part of your model and select the other part in the "Object:" box.

Answer (score -2):

Have you set your object as shade smooth? if yes, go to Objects > Shade flat

Answer (score -2):

Try to make a loop cut, or use the knife, for all polygons

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zUb9.png]